# BASH scripting to find one word sentences

Tags: regex, bash, scripting, matching

given the name of a file as an argument,the script reads the file name and creates a new file containing only lines which consist of one word.

An example input and output will be

```
There
are 20 students in the class.
[TAB][SPACE] Nearly
half of them are enrolled in FoS. The rest are in
Faculty-Of-ES.
```

The output from the script should look like

```
There
[TAB][SPACE] Nearly
Faculty-Of-ES.
```

Hello I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to learn bash scripting for over a month now but questions like this still stump me.
Please outline the general approach .Thank you

Comment: What is your definition of a "word"?

Comment: How are you defining a bash scripting? Can you invoke Perl or Python scripts? Awk? Sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -P "^[\s]*[0-9A-Za-z-]+.?[\s]*$" test.txt`

Where `test.txt` contains the input text.

Here I am defining a word as having **zero or more whitespace** in the beginning and end . Then **any combination of alphabets, digits and `-`** and **optionally ending with a period**.

**NOTE ::** This will not work if you are considering floating point  numbers as a word. Hence your definition of a `word` defines the result and the regex.

Comment: tried it ..it works thanks everyone.No I do not think we consider floating point numbers as word.

Comment: If you don't have `grep -P`, try the much simpler `egrep -i '[-a-z0-9][^-a-z0-9]+[-a-z0-9]' test.txt`

Answer (score 1):

probably the simplest way: `awk 'NF==1' filename`

Answer (score 0):

**Code**: `cat $1 | egrep "^\s*\w+\s*$" > output.txt`.

**Explanations**:

1. You can reference the variables your program get using `$1..$9` so if you run your program `$ > myprogram filename.txt` then `$1` will be `filename.txt`

2.You can read a file's content using `cat filename`. You can pipe the files content to the next line of code using `|` (pipe symbol).

1. You can use the `egrep` program to only show lines where a regular expression matches.
2. a regular expression to get only only one word lines might be: `^\s*\w+\s*$`. which reads: there can be zero or more spaces at the start of the line (\s - spaces, * is zero or more, ^ is the start of the line). then one or more characters (\w is letters, digits and underline, + is one or more). then zero or more spaces and then must be the end of the line. meaning this regular expression won't show the line 'something something' because it expects the end of the line after the space, not more words.
3. You can redirect the output of egrep to a file using redirections: `> filename`.

Comment: useless cat is useless. egrep can take a file argument.
also the regex doesn't confirm to the output required, the last one specifically